# Protecting specific object id from being deleted in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 97 objects ranging from **id=1** to **id=97** in my database that contain core data. Is there any way to protect only these **objects (=equals the column name)** from being deleted, **but not the entire column**?

---

```
|objects|
---------
id int primary key

some more non key attributes...
```

---

**SELECT * FROM objects** returns something like

```
id | ... 

1 | ...    // <- should be protected

2 | ...    // <- should be protected

3 | ...    // <- should be protected

... | ...

97 | ...    // <- last object to be protected

98 | ...  // <- should not be protected!!!
```

Comment: Consider using PostgreSQL instead as PostgreSQL has application user based record access policy out of the box.. In MySQL you have to simulate it with a `VIEW` and a function(s) explained more or less [here](https://mariadb.com/resources/blog/protect-your-data-row-level-security-in-mariadb-10-0/) .. note you have to modify the SQL code still to match your needs..

Comment: I have to create a view you are right, forgot about that

Comment: You could have a table that lists the `id`s that need to be protected and create a foreign key relationship with the records in your primary table. That way, when you attempt to delete the protected records, referential integrity would protect them.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by creating another table which references this table with a FOREIGN KEY constraint, and ON DELETE RESTRICT.

```
CREATE TABLE protected_objects (
    obj_id INT
    FOREIGN KEY(obj_id)
        REFERENCES objects(id)
        ON DELETE RESTRICT
)
```

You can create rows in the protected_objects table that lists the objects that should be protected. You can control the ability to protect and un-protect objects by restricting privileges on the protected_objects table as appropriate for your use case.